# How to fix 404 error if 'name' is posted as HTML Form Element name or key in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, wordpress-theming

I want to make custom form for WordPress Custom Theme/Plugin.

If I use "name" as any form element name and after I submit my form to database in WordPress then it redirects to "Error 404" Page.

```
<form action ="POST" action ="">
    <input type = "text" name = "name">
        <!---- OTHER ELEMENTS HERE ---->
    <input type = "submit">
</form>
```

Output: Error 404 - Page not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"name" is a reserved term in Wordpress, and you can't use it as a get or post variable, or else you will likely get an error like that. See the full list of reserved terms here:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Reserved_Terms

Try changing it to something else, like "username".

Answer (score 1):

I think "name" is a reserved term but the 404 error is not because of that. The 404 error is generated because there is a minor bug in your form element. You have used the attribute "action" twice while creating the form. Below is the code you can check. It works for me.

```
<form method ="POST" action ="THE_URL_YOU_WANT_TO_REDIRECT_TO">
    <input type = "text" name = "name">
        <!---- OTHER ELEMENTS HERE ---->
    <input type = "submit">
</form>
```